# Auto Update Render Window on motion blur properties change?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, motion-blur

Is it possible to have the render view update automatically instead of pressing manually F12 every time as I change motion blur effect properties? This is concerning Render view only and has nothing to do with viewport rendering because motion blur only gets applied in the render view if I am correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Message Bus](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html) to notify when settings change and then [render the image](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.render).

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
key = scene.render if scene.render.engine == 'CYCLES' else scene.eevee

def msgbus_callback():
    bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT")

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(key=key, owner=object(), args=(), notify=msgbus_callback)
```

FYI: this will render also when different settings are changed.

[image]

Comment: 10 seconds faster than me, good one!

Comment: @brockmann I know the pain, I wish there was a feedback like with edits, where you see an answer is being edited - for straight-forward answers like this it would save me some time.

Comment: Ez, no pain. Notice that the OP is asking for cycles motion blur.

Comment: @brockmann thanks, I didn't read the tags - updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This, much more elaborate code will allow for more interactive blur adjustment - still, sadly, I didn't find a way to cancel current render from script, so it's not as interactive as it could be. Perhaps it could be changed to render with 1 sample first and then increase the number of samples and re-render...

```
import bpy

class BlurPreviewOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator helping with interactive blur preview"""
    bl_idname = "render.blur_preview"
    bl_label = "for usage in a script"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}

    delay = .2  # how long to wait after a change to render
    timer_delay = 0.1  # accuracy of delay depends on this
    timer = None
    last_duration = 0
    rendering = None
    last_shutter = None
    shutter = None
    next_shutter = None

    def render_cancel(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # treating cancel the same way as completing
        # instead could add some more logic to allow the user to cancel once
        # to render the most recent setting faster, or cancel twice
        # to avoid rendering (set self.render_needed = False)
        self.render_complete(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def render_complete(self, scene, depsgraph=None):
        self.rendering = False
        self.last_shutter = self.next_shutter
        
    def add_handlers(self, C):
        print("add")
        bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.append(self.render_cancel)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(self.render_complete)
        self.timer = C.window_manager.event_timer_add(self.timer_delay, window=C.window)
        print(dir(self.timer))

    def cancel(self, C):
        bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.remove(self.rendering_stopped)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(self.rendering_stopped)
        C.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self.timer)

    def shutter_check(self, C):
        engine = C.scene.render.engine
        path = C.scene.render if engine == "CYCLES" else C.scene.eevee
        shutter = path.motion_blur_shutter
        if self.shutter != shutter:
            self.shutter = shutter
            self.last_duration = self.timer.time_duration
        
    def execute(self, C):
        self.add_handlers(C)
        C.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}    

    def modal(self, C, event):
        if event.type == "TIMER":
            self.shutter_check(C)
            if self.rendering or self.timer.time_duration < self.last_duration + self.delay:
                return {"PASS_THROUGH"}
            if self.last_shutter != self.shutter:
                self.rendering = True
                self.next_shutter = self.shutter
                bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}


bpy.utils.register_class(BlurPreviewOperator)
bpy.ops.render.blur_preview()
```